# Maven WAR JSP Project + MySQL + Tomcat: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for

Tags: mysql, maven, jsp, tomcat

I have tried everything but I cannot get it to work still.
So I am forced to ask the question here, in hope that I find the solution.
I am writing a very simple JSP Web application, to access a MySQL database locally here.
I am deploying the generated WAR file to Tomcat.
I am using latest versions (as of 9.8.2020) of MySQL (8.0.21) and Tomcat (9.0.37).
My Maven pom.xml has this:

```
...
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.21</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Then, my JSP file has these, (password not shown):

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix = "sql"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
<sql:setDataSource var="mystraDB" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mystra" user="root" password="###"/>

<sql:query var="result" dataSource="${mystraDB}">
    SELECT id, isbn, title FROM mystra.books;
</sql:query>
...
```

As I show in a lot of solutions, I have also copied the mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar file, into Tomcats lib folder.
I am using Visual Studio Code, and I am using its extension of Tomcat for Java, where I can start and stop Tomcat, and I can debug WAR package and test then from there.
The problem that I am having is this:

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for ${mystraDB}"

for the following line:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/fetchBooks.jsp] at line [30]

27:             <sql:setDataSource var="mystraDB" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
28:                 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mystra" user="root" password="###"/>
29: 
30:             <sql:query var="result" dataSource="${mystraDB}">
31:                 SELECT id, isbn, title FROM mystra.books;
32:             </sql:query>
33:
```

Do you have any remaining ideas about how I can solve this issue?
Everything not shown here, is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

For others having issues, I found what was the problem with my project.
I could not parse EL expressions with $.
So, I added this line to every jsp that I had:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Also I updated the web.xml, like so:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">
```